# OpenGL - Difference between ARB and non-ARB functions

Tags: opengl

I know that ARB means that function is an extension to OpenGL core, but if GLEW makes me able to use e.g.:

```
glCompileShaderARB()
```

and

```
glCompileShader()
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: All you need is to google for the answers : https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is only available if your implementation supports `GL_ARB_shader_objects`. This extension is not functionally identical to core GLSL, there are some minor things that were changed/removed from 3D Labs'/ARB's original design before it was promoted to core and of course a lot of function names changed.

For instance, `glGetObjectParameterivARB (...)` is thoroughly confusing if you are used to seeing `glGetShaderiv (...)` and `glGetProgramiv (...)`. When GLSL was promoted to core, they split that function up.

---

`glCompileShader (...)` is guaranteed to be available in anything that implements OpenGL 2.0+ and this is what you should always use unless you are dealing with ancient (~2004) drivers. All tutorials worth reading will be written against core GLSL, and there is no point in learning the ARB extension.